# image added from webview adds margin(space) but pure Image does not add any margin in layout

Tags: android, html, android-layout, webview, ads

I am trying to add banner ad in my android app.
but the banner loaded from webview showed with space or margin. I didn't specified margin anywhere.

Ad space for image is specified 300 x 50 means anything bigger than this go out of focus.

If this space is displayed in webview then image will be displayed partially or cropped from bottom and sides.

**This is Image added directly.**

[image]

**This is Image added from webview.**

[image]

any solution to avoid these margins because I can't customize fixed 300 x 50  fixed size of ad space.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
     <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bann" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ad space is 300 x 50. I can't illustrate it here in layout.. Its added by adserver SDK.

Comment: Could you please post your layout? Thanks.

Comment: @fasteque added the layout.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694184/remove-unwanted-white-space-in-webview-android

Comment: oh I found it in that post!! Solved. Thanks @fasteque. How can I accept this answer and mark this question as solved.  
I found that default margin and padding is 10px in html page(Never came across this fact :/ ).
added the style 
`<style type="text/css">

html, body {
margin: 0px;

padding: 0px;

}
</style>`

Comment: Glad you solved it, I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely there's a default margin/padding in the html page you show, please check this post to get the solution: [Remove unwanted White Space in WebView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694184/remove-unwanted-white-space-in-webview-android)