# How to remove unwanted whitespaces from webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, removing-whitespace

I am using Webview to load the response (contains HTML data) but it takes displays the data with some unwanted whitespaces for multiple line as well as single line.

I tried by using

```
                    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, comment_resp, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
                    webView.requestLayout();
                    webView.clearView();
```

while using above code some contents are not displaying. also tried with

```
        webView.setScrollBarSize(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove unwanted White Space in WebView Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694184/remove-unwanted-white-space-in-webview-android)

Comment: Can you edit the Html or CSS in the web page ?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? Could you please to share

Comment: used webView.requestLayout();  @RichardLe