# How to remove inbuilt margin in Android webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I am using android webview in my application.I noticed that it has the inbuilt margin.So need to remove it as per UI requirement.

I have used this it's getting the perfect result.

```
 @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.margin=\"0%\"; void 0");
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

it's getting refreshed when it's notified and it's looks as too bad.
 But we can apply the JavaScript to our html code as well right?
 I have used `<script> <script/>` over there but no result.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>a{color:#3D7B8A; text-decoration:none}</style>"+ getDescription().replace("<p>", "<p style= \"line-height: 150%; text-align: justify;\" >"), "text/html", "utf-8",
                    null);
```

Please advise.

Comment: When you load a javascript URL, it runs javascript which can modify the DOM of the document already loaded.  But if you don't have javascript: URL, it just thinks it's a new web page and replaces the already loaded document.

Comment: @krislarson right now the margin is removing from the webview but can we put javascript with the loadDataWithBaseURL?

Comment: You could try it with a base URL of "javascript:" and a mime type of "application/javascript", but I've never tried it so I don't know if it works.  I use `loadUrl` all the time for javascript because I know it works.

Comment: Have you tried removed all the margins by injecting in the `<head>` a style reset `* {margin: 0; padding: 0}`?

Comment: @avetisk yes i did <style>a{color:#3D7B8A; text-decoration:none} * {margin: 0; padding: 0} </style> but it remove the padding between line as well.

And i just need to remove the outline margin

Comment: If it works, then try `html, body, body > * { padding: 0; margin: 0 }`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, from the code above, you haven't made `padding = 0`.

I have look on Google and found this question and answer, you may want to have a look: [Remove unwanted White Space in WebView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699561/5666482)

> By default **webview** has some margin/padding in body. If you want to remove that padding/margin then override body **tag** and add margin like:
>
> `<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">`

Comment: yes I found same and tried it but didn't get desired result

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd. I hope you find a solution to your problem - if you haven't already.

Comment: it's remove the margin from out line but it also remove the padding from the paragraph :(

Comment: @SmitPatel: You could then do in CSS: `p { padding: 10px; }` or however much padding you want.