# ProgressBar gap

Tags: android, xml

[Check this image for the progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgWpY.png)

Any idea how to remove that little gap under the ProgressBar?
How can I achieve no gap? Should it be via java code in the MainActivity or...?
Here is my Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2.9dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/my_toolbar"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: give negative padding to ProgressBar

Comment: You mean a little margin sir?

Comment: yes marginBottom = -10dp like wise

Comment: Because it was already android:layout_alignBottom="@id/my_toolbar" I gave it a -2dip and it worked thank you sir for your help all the best! :)

Comment: Doesn't look like the space is from the `ProgressBar`.  It might be within the `WebView` - take a look here on how to remove (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694184/remove-unwanted-white-space-in-webview-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add just negative margin to the `Progressbar`

> Updated Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2.9dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-2dip"
/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```